# Generate CSS pattern for div

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, background, mousehover

I need to create a hover (mouseover) pattern for my menu, similar to this (yellow hover pattern on the home):

[image]

Currently what I am doing is using 3 images together combined to generate one hover effect image. The left and right images remain as such, but the center image is set to repeat. This is because the menu items text can be of any length (Example: Home, Faqs & Contact, etc.). Reference screenshot:

[image]

Is there any other optimal solution to achieve this, other than using 3 images? Like for example: To create some sort of rough edges around the div in CSS. I am not sure how this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SVG for the same. For hover effects over SVG, use JS event handlers.

**Run the code snippet** to check how it works.

[image: Hover Effect using SVG]

```js
function fillBG() {
     document.getElementById('banner').style.fill = "#f6c43c";
}
function fillTransparent() {
     document.getElementById('banner').style.fill = "transparent";
}
```

```css
#banner {
    fill: transparent;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <svg width="260" height="170" onmouseover="fillBG()" onmouseout="fillTransparent()">
        <defs>
            <filter id="filter" height="1.4" width="1.4">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.1" numOctaves="2" type="fractalNoise" result="res" />
                <feDisplacementMap in2="res" scale="70" result="res_2" xChannelSelector="R" in="SourceGraphic" />
                <feComposite in2="res_2" in="SourceGraphic" operator="atop" result="fbSourceGraphic" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect id="banner" filter="url(#filter)" width="250" height="100" x="10" y="0" />
        <foreignObject width="250" height="100">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">
                Header Info
            </h1>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```